# How to simplify my model code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I am new to Rails and I wonder if there's any way to simplify this code from my model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  def subtotal
    if price and quantity
      price * quantity
    end
  end

  def vat_rate
    if price and quantity
      0.19
    end
  end

  def total_vat
    if price and quantity
      subtotal * vat_rate
    end
  end

end
```

As far as I know *before_filter* does not work within models?

Comment: you return nil when price and quantity are not set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  VAT_RATE = 0.19

  def subtotal
    (price || 0) * (quantity || 0)
  end

  def total_vat
    subtotal * VAT_RATE
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would override the getter methods for price and quantity so that they return zero when not set, which allows your other methods to return valid results when no values are set rather than checking that they are and returning nil.

Additionally, creating a method to provide the VAT rate seems a little overkill for what should be a constant. If it isn't a constant then it should probably be stored in the DB so that it can be modified.

Here's a modification of your model based on my thoughts:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  VAT_RATE = 0.19

  def price
    self.price || 0
  end

  def quantity
    self.quantity || 0
  end

  def subtotal
    price * quantity
  end

  def total_vat
    subtotal * VAT_RATE
  end
end
```